# How to calculate the number of triminos?

Tags: combinatorics

It is known how to calculate the number of [domino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominoes) tiles.

The number of different is tiles $C^2_7=\frac{7!}{2!5!}=21$ plus the $7$ double tiles. Total number is 28 tiles.

**Question.** How to calculate the number of triominos?

Total number of triominos is 56 tiles.

[image]

Comment: the number of domino tiles is ${8\choose 2}$ essentially the double is equivalent of having one more number to choose from.  And the triminos have doubles and triples but the range is only $0-5$ ... ${8\choose 3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have $6$ choices for the numbers: $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$.

**Case 1:** All three numbers are different, ABC. To pick three different numbers from six, you end up computing $6\cdot5\cdot4/3! = 20$.

**Case 2:** AAB. Six choices for the repeated number, and five choices for the non-repeated number, so that the total is $6 \cdot 5= 30$.

**Case 3:** AAA. Six choices for the repeated number yields $6$ more possibilities.

**So:** The total is $20 + 30 + 6 = 56$ as claimed/desired.

**Note:** Personally, I would have counted, e.g., $123$ and $132$ as different (unless these can be flipped?) since they cannot be rotated from one to the other; however, I counted above in a way that would match the claimed answer of $56$.

Answer (score 1):

The number of triominoes is the number of multisets of 6 items taken 3 at a time, which is
$$\binom{6+3-1}{3} = 56$$
Reference: [Wikipedia on Multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets)